# DataTables GET parameters missing

Tags: get

I'm using the following init:

```
$('#PlaceHolder').dataTable(
    {
        "dom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "bDestroy"  : true,
        "iDisplayLength":10,
        "ajax": "../scripts/myDataTables_server_processing.php",
        "order": [[ 0, "desc" ]],
        "aoColumns":
            [
                {"bSortable": false},
                null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,
                {"bSortable": false},
                {"bSortable": false},
                {"bSortable": false}
            ],
        "tableTools":
        {
            "sSwfPath": "../resources/DataTables/extensions/TableTools/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf",
            "sRowSelect": "multi",
            "aButtons":
                [

                    {
                        "sExtends":    "copy",
                        "bSelectedOnly": "true"
                    },
                    // "print",
                    {
                        "sExtends":    "collection",
                        "sButtonText": "Save",
                        "aButtons":
                            [
                                {
                                    "sExtends":    "csv",
                                    "bSelectedOnly": "true"
                                },
                                {
                                    "sExtends":    "xls",
                                    "bSelectedOnly": "true"
                                },
                                {
                                    "sExtends":    "pdf",
                                    "bSelectedOnly": "true",
                                    "sPdfOrientation": "landscape",
                                    "sTitle": "Raport zgrzewania"
                                }
                            ]
                    }
                ]
        }

    }

).fnClearTable();
```

when ajax GET myDataTables_server_processing.php is called for data the header looks ok:

```
Query String Parametersview sourceview URL encoded
draw:13
columns[0][data]:0
columns[0][name]:
columns[0][searchable]:true
columns[0][orderable]:false
columns[0][search][value]:
columns[0][search][regex]:false
columns[1][data]:1
columns[1][name]:
columns[1][searchable]:true
columns[1][orderable]:true
columns[1][search][value]:
columns[1][search][regex]:false
columns[2][data]:2
columns[2][name]:
columns[2][searchable]:true
columns[2][orderable]:true
columns[2][search][value]:
columns[2][search][regex]:false
columns[3][data]:3
columns[3][name]:
columns[3][searchable]:true
columns[3][orderable]:true
columns[3][search][value]:
columns[3][search][regex]:false
columns[4][data]:4
columns[4][name]:
columns[4][searchable]:true
columns[4][orderable]:true
columns[4][search][value]:
columns[4][search][regex]:false
columns[5][data]:5
columns[5][name]:
columns[5][searchable]:true
columns[5][orderable]:true
columns[5][search][value]:
columns[5][search][regex]:false
columns[6][data]:6
columns[6][name]:
columns[6][searchable]:true
columns[6][orderable]:true
columns[6][search][value]:
columns[6][search][regex]:false
columns[7][data]:7
columns[7][name]:
columns[7][searchable]:true
columns[7][orderable]:true
columns[7][search][value]:
columns[7][search][regex]:false
columns[8][data]:8
columns[8][name]:
columns[8][searchable]:true
columns[8][orderable]:true
columns[8][search][value]:
columns[8][search][regex]:false
columns[9][data]:9
columns[9][name]:
columns[9][searchable]:true
columns[9][orderable]:true
columns[9][search][value]:
columns[9][search][regex]:false
columns[10][data]:10
columns[10][name]:
columns[10][searchable]:true
columns[10][orderable]:true
columns[10][search][value]:
columns[10][search][regex]:false
columns[11][data]:11
columns[11][name]:
columns[11][searchable]:true
columns[11][orderable]:true
columns[11][search][value]:
columns[11][search][regex]:false
columns[12][data]:12
columns[12][name]:
columns[12][searchable]:true
columns[12][orderable]:true
columns[12][search][value]:
columns[12][search][regex]:false
columns[13][data]:13
columns[13][name]:
columns[13][searchable]:true
columns[13][orderable]:false
columns[13][search][value]:
columns[13][search][regex]:false
columns[14][data]:14
columns[14][name]:
columns[14][searchable]:true
columns[14][orderable]:false
columns[14][search][value]:
columns[14][search][regex]:false
columns[15][data]:15
columns[15][name]:
columns[15][searchable]:true
columns[15][orderable]:false
columns[15][search][value]:
columns[15][search][regex]:false
order[0][column]:0
order[0][dir]:desc
start:10
length:10
search[value]:
search[regex]:false
_:1414344724424
Response Headersview source
Cache-Control:no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Type:text/html
Date:Sun, 26 Oct 2014 17:32:22 GMT
Expires:Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=95
Pragma:no-cache
Server:Apache/2.2.21 (FreeBSD) mod_ssl/2.2.21 OpenSSL/0.9.8q mod_fcgid/2.3.6
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
```

but when I output $GET in " myDataTables_server_processing.php" the last parameter that is available is "start" and no "length", nor "search" are available ("variable is not set") as if the GET url data was truncated.

What can be the reason for this?

Thanks

Tom

Comment: +1 since I reproduced it once in production (once for all...), I just wonder how this could happen... if anyone has a hint...